# How to make a partial queries in MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, partial

My data has this structure:

```
{
    "user": {
        "name":"John",
        "sports":[
            {"sId":"sport1","name":"basketball"},
            {"sId":"sport2",{"name":"tennis"},
            {"sId":"sport3","name":"surf"}, ...
            {"sId":"sportN","name":"golf"}
        ],
        "birthDate":"25/07/1960"
    }
}
```

and I'd like to filter to obtain the same user but only with the two first sports, such as:

```
{
    "user": {
        "name":"John",
        "sports":[
            {"sId":"sport1","name":"basketball"},
            {"sId":"sport2","name":"tennis"}
        ],
        "birthDate":"25/07/1960"
    }
}
```

and then the next two, ...

```
{
    "user": {
        "name":"John",
         "sports":[
            {"sId":"sport3","name":"surf"},
            {"sId":"sport4","name":"icehockey"}
        ],
        "birthDate":"25/07/1960"
    }
}
```

etcetera

but I do not know how to query it in mongo without getting the whole user

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: how come this is a valid document? Is 'sports' a list or map?

Comment: You are right. I have corrected the data. Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do ... why would you want to return repeated  user structure with only 2 array elements each? I'd strongly suggest you transform that on the client. Don't make the DB do that busy work.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, you can group the results later back so get the two sports back in the normal format:

```
db.so.aggregate(
    {$match : {'user.name':'John'}},
    {$unwind : '$user.sports'},
    {$skip: 0},
    {$limit : 2},
    {$group: {
        _id: '$_id', 
        name: { $first: '$user.name' }, 
        sports: { $push: '$user.sports' }, 
        birthDate: { $first: '$user.birthDate' }
    } }
);
```

Which then outputs:

```
{
    "result" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("51c71c8d4a01738f3eac69fc"),
            "name" : "John",
            "sports" : [
            {
                    "sId" : "sport1",
                    "name" : "basketball"
                },
                {
                    "sId" : "sport2",
                    "name" : "tennis"
                }
            ],
            "birthDate" : "25/07/1960"
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One alternative can be using aggregation framework:

```
db.testing.aggregate({$match : {'user.name':'John'}},{$unwind : '$user.sports'}, {$skip: 0}, {$limit : 2})
db.testing.aggregate({$match : {'user.name':'John'}},{$unwind : '$user.sports'}, {$skip: 2}, {$limit : 4})
```

Change the (0, 2) for (skip, limit) above to get the next set of 2.

Comment: That will not actually work. Each of the queries will give two documents as result, not one with an array of two sports.

Comment: I guess, those two returned documents are the actual array of two sports. Only difference is the format in which the values are returned.